# Defining "overloaded" functions in python

Tags: python, magic-methods, multiple-dispatch

I really like the syntax of the "magic methods" or whatever they are called in Python, like

```
class foo:
    def __add__(self,other): #It can be called like c = a + b
        pass
```

The call

```
c = a + b
```

is then translated to

```
a.__add__(b)
```

Is it possible to mimic such behaviour for "non-magic" functions? In numerical computations I need the Kronecker product, and am eager to have "kron" function such that

```
kron(a,b)
```

is in fact

```
a.kron(b)?
```

The use case is: I have two similar classes, say, matrix and vector, both having Kronecker product. I would like to call them

```
a = matrix()
b = matrix()
c = kron(a,b)

a = vector()
b = vector()
c = kron(a,b)
```

matrix and vector classes are defined in one .py file, thus share the common namespace. So, what is the best (Pythonic?) way to implement functions like above? Possible solutions:

1) Have one kron() functions and do type check

2) Have different namespaces

3) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The python default operator methods (`__add__` and such) are hard-wired; python will look for them because the operator implementations look for them.

However, there is nothing stopping you from defining a `kron` function that does the same thing; look for `__kron__` or `__rkron__` on the objects passed to it:

```
def kron(a, b):
    if hasattr(a, '__kron__'):
        return a.__kron__(b)
    if hasattr(b, '__rkron__'):
        return b.__rkron__(a)
    # Default kron implementation here
    return complex_operation_on_a_and_b(a, b)
```

Comment: For a complete solution, you might want to implement the full rule chain - ie, `kr = a.__kron__(b); if kr is not NotImplemented: return kr` (and same for `b.__rkron__` - and give `b` first go if it is a subclass of `type(a)`. But that might be overkill if you don't expect clients to make their own classes with their own strange definitions of something so domain specific.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) or *multimethods*.  Magic methods is one way to implement them, but it's actually more usual to have an object that you can register type-specific implementations on.

For example, http://pypi.python.org/pypi/multimethod/ will let you write

```
@multimethod(matrix, matrix)
def kron(lhs, rhs):
    pass

@multimethod(vector, vector)
def kron(lhs, rhs):
    pass
```

It's quite easy to write a multimethod decorator yourself; the BDFL describes a typical implementation in [an article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605).  The idea is that the `multimethod` decorator associates the type signature and method with the method name in a registry, and replaces the method with a generated method that performs type lookup to find the best match.

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, implementing something similar to the "standard" operator (and operator-like - think `len()` etc) behaviour is not difficult:

```
def kron(a, b):
    if hasattr(a, '__kron__'):
        return a.__kron__(b)
    elif hasattr(b, '__kron__'):
        return b.__kron__(a)
    else:
        raise TypeError("your error message here")
```

Now you just have to add a `__kron__(self, other)` method on the relevant types (assuming you have control over these types or they don't use slots or whatever else that would prevent adding methods outside the class statement's body).

Now I'd not use a `__magic__` naming scheme as in my above snippet since this is supposed to be reserved for the language itself.

Another solution would be to maintain a `type`:`specifici function` mapping and have the "generic" `kron` function looking up the mapping, ie:

```
# kron.py
from somewhere import Matrix, Vector

def matrix_kron(a, b):
    # code here

def vector_kron(a, b):
    # code here

KRON_IMPLEMENTATIONS = dict(
    Matrix=matrix_kron,
    Vector=vector_kron,
    )

def kron(a, b):
    for typ in (type(a), type(b)):
        implementation = KRON_IMPLEMENTATION.get(typ, None)
        if implementation:
            return implementation(a, b)
    else:
        raise TypeError("your message here")
```

This solution doesn't work well with inheritance but it "less surprinsing" - doesn't require monkeypatching nor `__magic__` name etc.

Comment: Why tie it to specific types? Now sub-classes or compatible imlementations are excluded. `for type_, imp in KRON_IMPLEMENTATION.iteritems(): if isinstance(a, type_)` would at least include sub-classes.

Comment: Also, the `__magic__` double-underscore names are not limited to python language features, per se. I think that if used as part of a documented API as hooks to override behaviour they are instantly recognizable as such. `zope.interface` uses [`__implemented__` and `__provides__`](http://apidoc.eea.europa.eu/zope.interface.interface.Specification-class.html#__implemented__) for example. Thus `__kron__` and `__rkron__` fit the usage beautifully.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I did mention that the second solution wouldn't work with inheritance (and simple `isinstance` checks may break depending on type order in the sequence and possible diamond inheritance). wrt/ `__magic__` names, the doc clearly states that these identifiers are reserved (http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers). Zope (and some other packages) don't respect this, but that's still not something to do without really good reasons - IOW : if you don't really need it, don't do it.

Comment: "Subject to breakage without warning" is something you have to deal with when upgrading major python versions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think having one single function that delegate the actual computation is a nice way to do it. If the Kronecker product only works on two similar classes, you can even do the type checking in the function :

```
def kron(a, b):
    if type(a) != type(b):
        raise TypeError('expected two instances of the same class, got %s and %s'%(type(a), type(b)))
    return a._kron_(b)
```

Then, you just need to define a `_kron_` method on the class. This is only some basic example, you might want to improve it to handle more gracefully the cases where a class doesn't have the `_kron_` method, or to handle subclasses.

Binary operations in the standart libary usually have a reverse dual (`__add__` and `__radd__`), but since your operator only work for same type objects, it isn't useful here.

Comment: `type(a) != type(b)` is a really bad idea - it won't handle subclasses, let alone ducktyping and the checks will pass for, eg, `kron('a', 'b')` even though that doesn't make sense. If you *really* want to do type checking, you'd want to do: `if not isinstance(a, matrix) or not isinstance(b, matrix):`. But it would be better to just check for the magic method.

Comment: I know, I said it in my answer. We're in the case where ``kron`` is only defined for objects of the same type, thus the type check (which would be ugly in any other situation, I agree).